# Can I use a lightning to USB cable to charge an iPhone through an iPad (iPadOS, Pro 9.7)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging

Since you can charge with the new iPad Pro, I was wondering if something similar could be done using the lightning to USB  adapter and the charging cable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an iPad Pro to charge other devices, including an iPhone.

According to Apple:

> To charge your iPhone or earlier-model iPad that has a Lightning port,
>   connect it to iPad Pro using the Apple USB-C to Lightning Cable. **If
>   you have a Lightning to USB cable, you can combine it with the Apple
>   USB-C to USB Adapter, then connect the adapter to iPad Pro.**

<sup>**Source:** [Charge and connect with the USB-C port on the new iPad Pro](https://support.apple.com/HT209186), Apple, [Bold emphasis mine].</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I meant using an old ipad pro using lightning cable, not the new one.